# Dad jokes program functions stalling

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm creating an interactive Node.js dad jokes generator for the "Mixed Messages" portfolio project on Codecademy, using the readline module to take in user input. I've divided the program into 3 separate functions that should be working in tandem: the greeting function `scriptInit()`, the joke generator `jokeGen()` and the repeat question sequence `goAgain()`.

I've tested all 3 functions separately and they work just fine, but when one function calls another, the program stalls in my command line (e.g. when I move from `scriptInit()` to `jokeGen()`, the program stalls after I provide a `response` to guess the punchline). What could be the issue?

```
/* REQUIRING NODE.JS READLINE MODULE */

const { read } = require('fs');

const readline = require('readline').createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});

/* PROGRAM START (GREETING) */

const scriptInit = () => {
    readline.question("Welcome, stranger! Are you ready to have a good laugh? (Yes/No)\n>> ", response => {
        const lcResponse = response.toLowerCase();
        const scriptCont = () => {
            if (lcResponse === "yes") {
                console.log("\nFantastic! Let's begin!\n");
            } else if (lcResponse === "no") {
                console.log("\nWell that's a shame; you don't really have a choice. Time for some jokes!\n")
            } else {
                console.log("\nI didn't understand that, but no matter ... let's get to these jokes!\n")
            }
        }

        setTimeout(scriptCont, 500);
        setTimeout(jokeGen, 2000);
        readline.close();
    });
}

/* JOKE RANDOMISER */

const jokeGen = () => {
    const disappointed = "\nArgh! You're no fun!";
    const jokes = [{
            question: "What do you call a government contract signed in a pub?",
            answers: ["bartender", "bar tender", "a bartender", "a bar tender"],
            response: "A BAR TENDER!",
        },
        {
            question: "What kind of shoes to artists wear?",
            answers: ["skechers", "sketchers"],
            response: "SKECHERS!",
        },
        {
            question: "What do you get from a pampered cow?",
            answers: ["spoiled milk", "spoilt milk"],
            response: "SPOILED MILK!",
        },
        {
            question: "What's an astronaut's favourite part of the computer?",
            answers: ["space bar", "spacebar", "the space bar", "the spacebar"],
            response: "The SPACE BAR!",
        },
        {
            question: "What did the coffee report to the police?",
            answers: ["mugging", "the mugging", "a mugging"],
            response: "A MUGGING!",
        },
        {
            question: "What's orange and sounds like a parrot?",
            answers: ["carrot", "a carrot"],
            response: "A CARROT!",
        },
        {
            question: "What do you call an alligator in a vest?",
            answers: ["investigator"],
            response: "A CARROT!",
        },
    ];
    const randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * jokes.length);

    readline.question(`${jokes[randNum]["question"]}\n>> `, response => {
        const lcResponse = response.toLowerCase();
        const answers = jokes[randNum]["answers"];
        const responseGen = () => {
            if (answers.includes(lcResponse)) {
                console.log(disappointed);
            } else {
                console.log(`\n${jokes[randNum]["response"]} Hahahahahaha xD`);
            }

            setTimeout(goAgain, 1000);
        }

        setTimeout(responseGen, 500);
        readline.close();
    });
}

/* REPEAT SEQUENCE */

const goAgain = () => {
    const randomQuestion = () => {
        const questions = ["Ready for another one?", "Wanna go again?", "Keep it going? I've got plenty more!", "Wanna laugh some more?", "Would you like another joke?"];
        const randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * questions.length);

        return questions[randNum] + " (Yes/No)\n>> ";
    }

    readline.question(randomQuestion(), response => {
        const lcResponse = response.toLowerCase();
        if (lcResponse === "yes") {
            console.log("\nSweet!\n");
            setTimeout(jokeGen, 1000);
        } else if (lcResponse === "no") {
            console.log("\nBummer. Until next time, then!");
        } else {
            console.log("\nI didn't catch that, but I'm guessing you wanna go again. Sweet!\n");
            setTimeout(jokeGen, 1000);
        }

        readline.close();
    });
}

/* CALLING FUNCTIONS */

scriptInit();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program stalls because you're closing the readline interface inside each callback. For example if you remove line 27 you'll see that it works:

```
// comment out this line and it works...
// readline.close();
```

But then, if you remove all readline.close() the program won't finish. So a simple solution would be to close the connection after the "Bummer. Until next time, then!" line like so:

```
   console.log("\nBummer. Until next time, then!");
   readline.close();
   process.exit(0);
```

On a larger note, you're experiencing a common problem in javascript: callback hell. There are lots of modern ways around that and one is to use Promises: (search for promises and Async Await). You might also want to look at an npm module like [inquirer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/inquirer) instead of readline because it can add a lot of nice usability. Inquirer already uses promises so it could be a good next step.

Comment: No problem. How could I resist a Dad jokes question!? Nice project, good luck with it.

Comment: Lol @digibake if you're looking to add to the cringe, you can fork the project on GitHub: https://github.com/DavyK17/mixed-messages